# How develop node modules locally using npm link in react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

I want to add my custom build botframework-webchat in reactproject

I have tried adding using npm link.***I get the following Error***

```
 Vostro-270s:~/React/Botframework webchat/chatbot$ npm link ./BotFramework-WebChat-3
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTYPE
npm ERR! typeerror Error: Argument #2: Expected array but got string
npm ERR! typeerror     at EventEmitter.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:190:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at Object.commandCache.(anonymous function) (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:156:13)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/link.js:93:24
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:282:31
npm ERR! typeerror     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/.npm/_logs/2019-07-16T11_35_13_546Z-debug.log
```

I have My BotFramework-WebChat-3 and My React app in a folder.
I'm tring to integrate Microsoft Botframework in my react app.
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

*** Hard: In your React website, incorporate a custom build of the Web Chat component ***
The simplest approach is to clone (or fork) this repo, alter it, build it, then reference your local build in your project's package.json as follows:

```
dependencies: {
    ...
    'botframework-webchat': 'file:/path/to/your/repo'
    ...
}
```

Running npm install will copy your local repo to node_modules, and import/require references to 'botframework-webchat' will resolve correctly.

You may also wish to go so far as to publish your repo as its own full-fledged, versioned npm package using npm version and npm publish, either privately or publicly.

Different projects have different build strategies, yours may vary considerably from the above. If you come up with a different integration approach that you feel would have broad application, please consider filing a pull request for this README.

Comment: can you list more information about how you are doing?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

try run `npm link /path/to/your/repo` and don't forget to remove node_modules from your custom repo